# How to handle error on Remote Images

Tags: imageresizer

Using the RemoteReader plugin, whats the best way to handle the remote server throwing an error (400 or 500)?

We retrieve images from remote sites and display them to users on our site. In some cases, the remote sites are generating server errors which is leading to broken images on our side.

e.g. this URL http://a5.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/599279_10151100083213818_1442454235_n.jpg returns a 400 error.

Ideally in this situation I'd like the 404 plugin to take effect so we at least present our users with something.

Is this possible?

**EDIT**
I should add, I'm using the URL API for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The [Image404](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/image404) plugin is designed to work with all storage providers, and permit placeholder images to be used instead in any 404 scenario.

The handling of 500 errors isn't currently supported, as that would be confusing for users trying to debug failed storage connections.

However, as the plugins are open-source, it would be trivial to fork the plugins and make these modifications yourself - just keep in mind that you'll be making debugging quite tricky later on.